# bootstrap grid not working as expected for different screen sizes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a page with a single image on it.
I have four versions of the image, one for each of the default Bootstrap 3 break points.
When using a desktop browser, the images behave pretty much as I expect (showing the correct version of the image at different screen sizes).
But when I test on other devices (Galaxy S2 phone, Nexus 7 tablet, iPad retina display) I am not getting the expected results.

For example, the Galaxy S2 phone claims to have 480x800px screen. The Bootstrap documentation (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) says the small screen setting is triggered by >=768px, so I should be seeing the small screen image in the S2 when in landscape orientation, but instead it is using the extra small (XS) image.

I get a similar issue with the Nexus 7. The docs say it's screen is 1920x1200, so I should be seeing the large screen image on either orientation, but instead I'm getting the medium image on portrait orientation.

Similar with the iPad. Docs say the screen should be 2048x1563, but is portrait orientation, I'm seeing the small screen image instead of either the medium or large.

What am I missing?
Do these devices report their screen sizes differently?

Answer (score 0):

Design for the iPad like it's 1024x768. The 2048x1563 is technically right, but this is the "Retina Display".  Something tells me it would be something similar for the other devices.  I know that iPhone 5 is 320px wide.

If you use Chrome, hit F12 to go to into Developer Tools, then click the little mobile phone in the top left corner.  Select the device you would like to use and use those dimensions.

It seems counter-intuitive, but it is what it is.

I hope this helps you out!